# How to fix this problem with WordPress search field?

Tags: wordpress, search, field

When I try to add search field in header on WordPress I got a problem. The letter "T" is changed with a symbol [image]

Anyone have an idea how to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To me it looks like it's a problem with the font, where the character code for "t" got replaced with this icon. Can you tell us about the font you are using? Are any other "t" with the same font displayed as this icon?

Comment: In the same font aren't any other "t" as this icon. But I changed the font and seems to work. It never occurred to me that it was from the font.. Thank you!